# Change link values in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and stuck on the following code:

```
div class="hd-box-wrap">                                
h2> a href=" ?php the_permalink();?>">?php the_title();?></a>/h2>
```

Now suppose if this hyperlink give me a value

> www.google.com/ankit

but I need my page to go to

> www.google.com/ankit1

I have tried

```
div class="hd-box-wrap">                                
h2> a href=" ?php the_permalink();?1>">?php the_title();?></a>/h2>
```

but I am not able to figure out rest. There is no mistake of "<" I have removed because of issue in stackoverflow.

Comment: You can press the { } icon to wrap your code in a block which would stop SO from doing things with your "<" and also make the code look better.

Answer (score 0):

use the substr_replace() function to change the last character from / to 1
Like this:

```
a href=" <?php substr_replace(the_permalink(), "1", -1); ?>"
```

Comment: sorry its taking as http://localhost/wordpress/portfolio/ankit/1/ instead

Comment: So the the_permalink() function returns "ankit/", and you want it to go to "http://google.com/ankit/1" ?

Comment: no i want it to go ankit1. actually its a portfolio gallary page which directs to portfolio. i want to direct it to another page

Comment: localhost/wordpress/portfolio/ankit1 or localhost/wordpress/ankit or localhost/wordpress/ankit1. anything will wor as i will give my new page that same url

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Sorry no change in url its loading as starting

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<div class="hd-box-wrap">
    <h2>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>1"><?php the_title();?></a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: its gives output as /ankit/1 not ankit1

Comment: How about `<?php home_url(); ?>1`